# How to exit powershell from a sourced script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Consider "outer.ps1":

```
"in outer.ps1"
. .\inner.ps1
"in outer.ps1 after sourcing inner.ps1"
```

that sources "inner.ps1" which just exits:

```
exit 0
```

When I run "outer.ps1" the output indicates that the exit only returns from "inner.ps1":

```
in outer.ps1
in outer.ps1 after sourcing inner.ps1
```

Is it possible to exit the powershell process from inner.ps1? I don't want to throw an exception, this would be a normal termination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```
[Environment]::Exit(0)
```

But be warned - it will exit the PowerShell console completely.  That's a pretty big hammer.  :-)

A better way is to use a trap handler in outer.ps1 e.g.:

```
trap { exit 0 }
```

And in inner.ps1 do a throw e.g.:

```
throw "Inner.ps1 done!"
```

Comment: The hammer is good. I like it, thanks) Just in place to emulate the bash behaviour.

Comment: I wish `trap` printed the throw message but it's ok